# Exception while creating a Jenkins job - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: jenkins, tomcat7

I am getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when trying to create a new job in Jenkins.

Here are details:

- Installed Tomcat 7
- Installed Jenkins as war (copied Jenkins war)
- Env : Ubuntu
- Ran the following commands:

  `$ export JENKINS_HOME=/path/to/jenkins_home/`

  `$ catalina.sh start`

The following is the exception stack trace I got when trying to create a new job:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: -1
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:777)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:841)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:630)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:224)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:96)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: -1
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.OrderRetainingMap.entrySet(OrderRetainingMap.java:77)
    at java.util.HashMap.putAllImpl(HashMap.java:678)
    at java.util.HashMap.putAll(HashMap.java:669)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.OrderRetainingMap.<init>(OrderRetainingMap.java:36)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.FieldDictionary.buildMap(FieldDictionary.java:135)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.FieldDictionary.fieldsFor(FieldDictionary.java:76)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:127)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doMarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:143)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:102)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:43)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.start(TreeMarshaller.java:82)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.marshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:37)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:898)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:887)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:860)
    at hudson.XmlFile.write(XmlFile.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractItem.save(AbstractItem.java:455)
    at hudson.model.Job.save(Job.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.save(AbstractProject.java:283)
    at hudson.model.ItemGroupMixIn.createProject(ItemGroupMixIn.java:268)
    at hudson.model.ItemGroupMixIn.createTopLevelItem(ItemGroupMixIn.java:175)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.doCreateItem(Jenkins.java:2930)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:297)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:160)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:120)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:727)
    ... 38 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem using a JDK 8 with Windows 8.1, I solved it by switching to a JDK 7 (7.0.52).